# How do I load a .php page from another page and load dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have a grocery store web page index.html with a navigation to different product categories (Fruits, Meats, Snacks etc...), then I have a page named aisle.php which will display all of the products from the category, and it gets all of the products from a json file.
I'm wondering how do I redirect to the aisle.php page and load the products I want, since I need to know which link was clicked. I'm new to php and json and it's what we are required to use for our class, thanks in advance!

[Image of the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE1Gx.jpg)

[Image of the aisle page with sample products hardcoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1gF2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can form your link to aisle.php with a parameter in query string like so :
`<a href='aisle.php?content=Meats'></a>`
and in aisle.php your can check the parameters via $_GET variable and show the products you need

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this :

- using **GET** variables (probably the easiest as a beginner, but also the dirties)
- using **POST** variables (through an HTML form)
- setting up an **URL redirection** (cleanest but probably not easy to beginners)

Once your variable is sent, you can save it into a **SESSION** or a **COOKIE**.

I suggest you read about [PHP superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)